# jQueryUI dialog form does not open

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery and I am having a problem with displaying a lightbox form. I want a form simlilar to **[this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)**. However, I have no idea how to customize it

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Light Box</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        });         

        $("#create-uer")
            .button()
            .click(function(){
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-form">
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Schlagwort</label>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you loading only jquery-UI or have you omitted the line where you are loading the foundation library (you need to load jquery before you can use UI)? Also `$("#create-uer")` looks like a blatant typo to me (user?) as well as there is no element like this in your HTML?

Comment: The source of the code they used is available on the site you gave.

Comment: yeah, I downloaded it and I tried to customize it. I just include the jquery ui file to the page because I don't see they include in their source code. And actually, I don't know which script file it needs also

Comment: Just use the latest version of jQuery, preferably from a CDN like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and make sure you load it **before** you load your custom UI build.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. Here I can go through it's style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add jquery.css before this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Download jquery from this page

```
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery
```

and add it your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look like the jQuery UI-form, you need to include their stylesheet as well.

Under [Themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) you can choose and customize the look and feel that you want, and then include that CSS on your page.

Comment: Yeah, but I only test for the action when the user clicks on the button, and then the lightbox lights up. But actually it does not work here, and I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

You still need to load the jQuery library before you can use jQuery UI (which is basically just an "official" plugin - therefore its methods and working rely on jQuery functionality). The fastest and recommended way to include jQuery would be loading it from a CDN (Content Distribution Network) and fall back to a local version in case the CDN fails.

From **[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //try to load from Google's CDN
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="myScriptDir/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script> //in case the jQuery object does not exist (i.e. not loaded) fall back to a local copy
```

Also make sure this is happening *before* you load the UI library.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
function openDialog() {

    $('#dialog').remove();

    $('#content').prepend('<div id="dialog" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;"><iframe src="URL of HTML page" style="padding:0; margin: 0; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>');

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: 'Title of dialog',

        close: function (event, ui) {
              // Code which you want to run at the time of close dialog box;
        },  
        bgiframe: false,
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false
    });
};
```

In this case you just need to put this above function at the Click event of particular button OR link. This will helpful to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 450,
        modal: true,
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    });         

    $("#create-user")
        .click(function(){
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>
```